# Encrypt a string using a public key

Tags: python, encryption

I need to take a string in Python and encrypt it using a public key.

Can anyone give me an example or recommendation about how to go about doing this?

Comment: What have you found with your Google search for "public key encryption in python"?  Anything?

Comment: Also, just for the record, it's very unusual to encrypt a string with a public key as such. The standard thing to do is randomly generate a "session key" to use with a symmetric cipher (using a secure random source, e.g., /dev/random), encrypt your message using the symmetric cipher, and then encrypt the session key using the public key.

Comment: @Chris: Not if he's talking about (for example) email - for email, encrypting with the public key is a perfectly normal thing to do.

Comment: @Richie: No, it's not. Even when encrypting emails (say, with gpg), the protocol described above is used. Think about the scenario if you're encrypting an email to 5 people, any one of whom can read it. The email is not encrypted 5 times! A session key is generated, which is used to encrypt the email (via a symmetric cipher), and then the session key is encrypted 5 times, each time to a different recipient.

Comment: Even the ezPyCrypto library you linked to uses session keys "behind the scenes", even if not directly exposed through the API. (The line "Choose between RSA and ElGamal for public key, and IDEA, DES3, Blowfish, ARC4, IDEA for session key" on their page hints at the existence of session keys.)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a Python cryptography library to do this.

Have a look at [ezPyCrypto](http://freenet.mcnabhosting.com/python/ezPyCrypto/): *"As a reaction to some other crypto libraries, which can be painfully complex to understand and use, ezPyCrypto has been designed from the ground up for absolute ease of use, without compromising security."*

It has an API:

```
encString(self, raw)
```

which looks like what you're after: *"High-level func. encrypts an entire string of data, returning the encrypted string as binary."*

Answer (score 2):

[PyMe](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/) provides a Python interface to the [GPGME](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/) library.

You should, in theory, be able to use that to interact with GPG from Python to do whatever encrypting you need to do.

Here's a **very simple** code sample from the [documentation](http://pyme.sourceforge.net/doc/pyme/index.html):

***This program is not for serious encryption, but for example purposes only!***

```
import sys
from pyme import core, constants

# Set up our input and output buffers.

plain = core.Data('This is my message.')
cipher = core.Data()

# Initialize our context.

c = core.Context()
c.set_armor(1)

# Set up the recipients.

sys.stdout.write("Enter name of your recipient: ")
name = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
c.op_keylist_start(name, 0)
r = c.op_keylist_next()

# Do the encryption.

c.op_encrypt([r], 1, plain, cipher)
cipher.seek(0,0)
print cipher.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the ezPyCrypto library that was recommended in another answer.
Please don't use this library. It is very incomplete and in some cases incorrect and highly insecure. Public key algorithms have many pitfalls and need to be implemented carefully.
For example, RSA message should use a padding scheme such as PKCS #1, OAEP etc to be secure. This library doesn't pad. DSA signatures should use the SHA1 hash function. This library uses the broken MD5 hash and there is even a bigger bug in the random number generation. Hence the DSA implementation is neither standards conform nor secure. ElGamal is also implemented incorrectly.

Following standards does make implementations somewhat more complex. But not following any is not an option. At least not if you care about security.

Answer (score 0):

An even "simpler" example without the use of any additional libraries would be:

```
def rsa():
# Choose two prime numbers p and q
p = raw_input('Choose a p: ')
p = int(p)

while isPrime(p) == False:
    print "Please ensure p is prime"
    p = raw_input('Choose a p: ')
    p = int(p)

q = raw_input('Choose a q: ')
q = int(q)

while isPrime(q) == False or p==q:
    print "Please ensure q is prime and NOT the same value as p"
    q = raw_input('Choose a q: ')
    q = int(q)

# Compute n = pq
n = p * q

# Compute the phi of n
phi = (p-1) * (q-1)

# Choose an integer e such that e and phi(n) are coprime
e = random.randrange(1,phi)

# Use Euclid's Algorithm to verify that e and phi(n) are comprime
g = euclid(e,phi)
while(g!=1):
    e = random.randrange(1,phi)
    g = euclid(e,phi)

# Use Extended Euclid's Algorithm 
d = extended_euclid(e,phi)

# Public and Private Key have been generated
public_key=(e,n)
private_key=(d,n)
print "Public Key [E,N]: ", public_key
print "Private Key [D,N]: ", private_key

# Enter plain text to be encrypted using the Public Key
sentence = raw_input('Enter plain text: ')
letters = list(sentence)

cipher = []
num = ""

# Encrypt the plain text
for i in range(0,len(letters)):
    print "Value of ", letters[i], " is ", character[letters[i]]

    c = (character[letters[i]]**e)%n
    cipher += [c]
    num += str(c)
print "Cipher Text is: ", num

plain = []
sentence = ""

# Decrypt the cipher text    
for j in range(0,len(cipher)):

    p = (cipher[j]**d)%n

    for key in character.keys():
        if character[key]==p:
            plain += [key]
            sentence += key
            break
print "Plain Text is: ", sentence

# Euclid's Algorithm
def euclid(a, b):
if b==0:
   return a
else:
   return euclid(b, a % b)

# Euclid's Extended Algorithm
def extended_euclid(e,phi):
d=0
x1=0
x2=1
y1=1
orig_phi = phi
tempPhi = phi

while (e>0):
  temp1 = int(tempPhi/e)
  temp2 = tempPhi - temp1 * e
  tempPhi = e
  e = temp2

  x = x2- temp1* x1
  y = d - temp1 * y1

  x2 = x1
  x1 = x
  d = y1
  y1 = y

  if tempPhi == 1:
      d += phi
      break
return d

# Checks if n is a prime number
def isPrime(n):
for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i == 0:
        return False
return True

character = {"A":1,"B":2,"C":3,"D":4,"E":5,"F":6,"G":7,"H":8,"I":9,"J":10,
     "K":11,"L":12,"M":13,"N":14,"O":15,"P":16,"Q":17,"R":18,"S":19,
     "T":20,"U":21,"V":22,"W":23,"X":24,"Y":25,"Z":26,"a":27,"b":28,
     "c":29,"d":30,"e":31,"f":32,"g":33,"h":34,"i":35,"j":36,"k":37,
     "l":38,"m":39,"n":40,"o":41,"p":42,"q":43,"r":44,"s":45,"t":46,
     "u":47,"v":48,"w":49,"x":50,"y":51,"z":52, " ":53, ".":54, ",":55,
     "?":56,"/":57,"!":58,"(":59,")":60,"$":61,":":62,";":63,"'":64,"@":65,
     "#":66,"%":67,"^":68,"&":69,"*":70,"+":71,"-":72,"_":73,"=":74}
```