# Python Encryption: Encrypting password using PGP public key

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, gnupg

I have the key pair generated by the GPG. Now I want to use the public key for encrypting the password. I need to make a function in Python. Can somebody guide me on how to do this?

I studied the Crypto package but was unable to find out how to encrypt the password using the public key.

I also read about the chilkat Python encryption library, but it is not giving the desired output. Maybe I don't how to use this library at the SSH secure shell client. Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [PyGPGME](https://www.ohloh.net/p/pygpgme)

Answer (score 0):

See also the answers provided to the following questions found in this search `Python Encryption` questions at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption+python) :

- [Python and PGP/encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048722)
- [Encrypt a string using a public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043382)
- [How to do PGP in Python (generate keys, encrypt/decrypt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020320)